# How to append the class of a clicked link to the end of the href of another anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I'm working on a website that makes use of isotope filters and hash history.
However, in order for my filters to work I need `#filter=.print` to be added after the permalink of my thumbnails `"a.perma"`. the `".print"` is the class of the filter thats being clicked `"option-set a"`. In this case the print filter.
I am not too skilled at jQuery and any help would be appreciated.
Here's the code I've been messing with:

```
var myClass;

jQuery("option-set a").click(function() {
    myClass = jQuery(this).attr("class");
});

jQuery("a.perma").each(function() {
    var _href = jQuery(this).attr("href"); 
    jQuery(this).attr("href", _href + myClass);
});
```

Comment: Why on click? why can't you just immediately append the `#filter=.print` to all your thumbs?

Comment: @roXon The question title says "of a clicked link" so I'd assume they only want it to happen when a link is clicked.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yes, but he also says that he has only **one** class, the `.print` so now I'll ask again. why on click :)

Comment: @roXon As I said before: because they *only want it to happen when a link is clicked on* - the number of classes is totally irrelevant to that. Whether they have one or a million classes, if they don't want it to happen until a link is clicked on, they need a click event handler. Also, as a guess, I'd say that the question is badly worded and `print` is merely one example of many classes.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm just 'wow'ed how we cannot get a voice from the OP

Comment: Sorry about the bad wording everybody. Yes the.print class is just one example of many classes. I need it to be assigned on click because I need the class assigned to reflect what filter was clicked. In this case "print" but it could be "identity", "portfolio" etc... Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code. Removes any previous filters. Keeps the permalink value even after going to another page and coming back. Uses `localStorage`.

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
    var oldClass = localStorage.getItem("permalink");

    if(oldClass != null && oldClass != "") {
        jQuery("a.perma").each(function() {
            var _href = jQuery(this).attr("href"); 
            _href = _href.split("#")[0];

            jQuery(this).attr("href", _href + "#filter=." + oldClass);
        });
    }
}

jQuery("option-set a").click(function() {
    myClass = jQuery(this).attr("class");

    jQuery("a.perma").each(function() {
        var _href = jQuery(this).attr("href"); 
        _href = _href.split("#")[0];

        jQuery(this).attr("href", _href + "#filter=." + myClass);

        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
            localStorage.setItem("permalink", myClass);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Both of these answers worked thanks for your help. The issue Im running into now is that the class keeps getting assigned to the end of the permalink with each click so if I click on print then web then photography the url of the permalink would appear as: /#filter=.print#filter=.web#filter=.photography   which still works, however it would be great if for the sake of tidiness it only displayed the last one. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If its not too much to ask do you think you could help me out with one last thing?: Once a thumbnail is clicked and the next page is loaded, I need the thumbnails to maintain the current permalink of the filter selected. Any ideas would be appreciated. I just cant seem to figure this out. I truly appreciate the help!!

Comment: You mean, when you go back to the page?

Comment: For that, you will need to use `localStorage`.

Comment: No.. for when the thumbnail is clicked and the work page is loaded. I need the process to repeat.

Comment: someone suggested I use [webstorage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) but Im not sure if thats the simplest way. for me atleast.

Comment: By thumbnail, you mean the `a.perma`, right? When you click on that, you will go to another page, right?

Comment: yes when a.perma is clicked and it goes to the next page. I would like the thumbnails to retain the permalink structure from the page before, unless a new filter is clicked

Comment: Understood, you should use webstorage, which is what I meant by `localStorage`. Give me some time, working on a viable solution...

Comment: AWESOME! worked like a charm! due to the fact that local storage is html5 this prob wont work on all browsers right? just curious?

Comment: Yeah, it won't work on all. But, HTML5 is supported by most of the current browsers.

Comment: Cool just making sure. I hate to be that guy. I thought I was there but apparently its making all the permalinks the same switching gears link http://427design.com/newsite/ourwork/switching-gears-bike-user-map/#filter=.

Comment: If only I could repay you for all your help! You have no idea how much I needed this

Comment: Thank you!! :) do you have any idea why thats happening? I changed input to (.option-set a) the permalinks are all screwed up.

Comment: there is now switching-gears-bike-user-map before the #filter in all the permalinks

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Don't you need `switching-gears-bike-user-map` before the "#"?

Comment: no i need the permalink of the thumbnail followed by#filter. switching-gears-bike-user-map would be before the # but only for the switching gears thumbnail. like the way it was before the last edit.

Comment: basically none of my permalinks work anymore. its making them all the same

Comment: the permalinks were working before you added the code for localstorage.

Comment: Understood, the issue is with the old localStorage value. Let me give you a fix.

Comment: Here, I have updated the answer, use the new code. Also, copy paste this in your browser address bar: `javascript:localStorage.setItem('permalink', '');`.

Comment: The issue was, localStorage stores the last value of the permalink in the browser, which will be taken the next time. Let me make a better fix.

Comment: so I just paste this in chromes address bar by itself?

Comment: I think im missing something. I updated the code. Is it working for you?

Comment: I apologize for my jquery noobness!

Comment: Have you pasted in address bar?

Comment: like so http://427design.com/newsite/our-work/localStorage.setItem('permalink',%20'');

Comment: NO, just paste the code starting with javascript, nothing else in the address bar.

Comment: Oh ok I see what it did now. yes that worked, but apparently i need to do that everytime on every page that loads

Comment: Yeah, I know... have updated the answer... now you won't need to do anything... it will work everywhere...

Comment: I see it is working now... just click on another filter to clear the last filter...

Comment: Awesome that worked!!! last tiny thing.... when the default http://427design.com/newsite/our-work/  page is loaded and no filters are selected, it defaults to the last one that was clicked. apparently its getting it from the cache is there a workaround for that. If not its cool ill try to figure it out. youve helped me soo much already, I feel bad.

Comment: Actually i dont think ill be able to figure it out sadly.

Comment: The issue was resolved after clearing my history. I just wanted to say thank you for all the help and for bearing with me!! You sir are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#computed-attr-values) with a function to determine and set the new value to avoid having to iterate and get/set separately.

```
jQuery("option-set a").click(function() {
    var myClass = this.className; // same as $(this).attr('class');
    jQuery('a.perma').attr('href', function(i, oldHref) {
        return oldHref + '.' + myClass;
    });
});
```

Depending on what the original `href` attributes look like you may have to add more or less to the string; I've assumed in the above that the `#filter=` part is already included. You may also want to check that it's not already in the existing `href` so it's not added more than once.